# Get-VM intermittent failure for VMs on local machine

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

We recently started having intermittent failures on some powershell scripts that manipulate VMs. I was able to reduce the problem to the following:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
for ($i=0;$i -lt 100000; $i=$i+1) {get-vm * | write-host}
```

This command will run and print the local Hyper-V VMs (there are currently 4) for a while (hundreds or thousands of times), but eventually will fail with:

```
PS>TerminatingError(Get-VM): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The computer 'LOCALNAME' could not be resolved. Make sure you typed the machine name correctly and that you have network access."
```

I can then look at the current $Error variable to get more info about the exception stack, which I've pasted below. The local machine's name is `LOCALNAME`. Any thoughts on what might lead to this kind of intermittent failure or how to diagnose it? I've looked through the event logs without any luck so far, and I'm close to just reimaging the machine.

```
PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualizationException: The computer 'LOCALNAME' could not 
                        be resolved. Make sure you typed the machine name correctly and that you have network access. 
                        ---> Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.ServerConnectionException: The computer 
                        'LOCALNAME' could not be resolved. Make sure you typed the machine name correctly and 
                        that you have network access.
                           at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.ServerNames.Resolve(String nameToResolve, 
                        IUserPassCredential credential)
                           at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.Server.GetServer(String name, 
                        IUserPassCredential credential)
                           at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.ParameterResolvers.GetServers(IServerParameters 
                        cmdletParameters, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
                           at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.ParameterResolvers.ResolveVirtualMachines(IVirtualMa
                        chineCmdlet vmCmdlet, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher, ErrorDisplayMode errorDisplayMode)
                           at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM.EnumerateOperands(IOperationWatcher 
                        operationWatcher)
                           at 
                        Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.VirtualizationCmdlet`1.PerformOperation(IOperationWatcher 
                        operationWatcher)
                           at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.VirtualizationCmdletBase.PerformOperationWithLogging
                        (IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
```

Comment: We've had similar problems - narrowed it down to DNS randomly dropping. I wrote an nslookup check which looped through hundreds of thousands of times and logged it's success/failure. We were able to pinpoint that once or twice an hour, DNS would stop resolving anything for only a second or two then recover. Still not sure the root cause of the DNS errors, but that was causing our app errors. Just a thought!

Comment: Thanks for the thought Nick. I think that is actually what is going on for us too. We've had our dns server acting up around the time of at least some of the problems. Kindof bizarre sense it is for the local machine... if it starts happening again, I may see if specifying a -ComputerName of 127.0.0.1 helps avoid the attempted name lookups